# Prove that only those points satisfying y-y1=m(x-x1) can lie on the line L passing through P1(x1,y1) with slope m.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, slope

First question, go easy on me. =)

From text: **Show that only those points satisfying $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$ can lie on the line $L$ passing through $P_1(x_1,y_1)$ with slope $m$.**

I can evaluate $m$ from two points: $P_1(x_1,y_1)$ and $P(x,y)$, and plug all these values into the point-slope form to give me the equation for a line ($L_1$).

Furthermore, I can demonstrate that a second line ($L_2$) has a slope equal to the slope of $L_1$, but at different $Ps$ in the plane. $L_1$ || $L_2$ if and only if $L_1$ and $L_2$ have equal slopes and the set of $Ps$ defining the lines $L_1$ and $L_2$ are unique from each other.

Though I've demonstrated that the points on $L_1$ are unique from the points on $L_2$, I'm not sure that I am answering this rigorously enough or proving the statement completely true. What am I missing? Or do I have this completely backwards?

TYIA.

Comment: Have you considered proving this by way of contradiction? i.e. assume that some point lies on the line but doesn't satisfy the given condition

Comment: I've tried to do this, but I don't think it can be proved. If we assume all lines travel infinitely along the axes then at some point on that line, another line will intersect that line or, at the very least, a point on another line will form a new line. I received assistance on this problem in a different forum and I found the proof can be solved by demonstrating the relationship between the slope formula and how you can derive the point-slope line formula. Thanks for your help!